# Font awesome icon defined in css

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I am using Font Awesome Free 5.5.0 and define icon in css, like this.

```
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
    content: "\f007";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}
```

it works fine, but just for few icons. I need to use [this one](https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-down?style=solid), with code "f107". But this code doesn´t work. 
I can find this code even in my linked font-awesom file in project, with same class name as in documentation, but when i use it in css, nothing happend.

Comment: you need font-weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css will work fine. we have to set font weight to define the solid icon.

```
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
    content: "\f007";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need define an icon specially in your CSS file.
If you have loaded font-awesome, it should be already available.
Have you tried `<i class="fas fa-angle-down" />`?

Demo here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6zyxjqw/1/)